# Why is Aptitude package manager not as popular as APT?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, package-management, aptitude

Let me admit that my perception implied by the question may be wrong. 
*(Aptitude may be more popular by users than APT;
unfortunately, I did not find robust data about usage.)* 
But, wherever I see, let's say, official documentation, manpages, installation instructions, tutorials and videos,
I mostly see the mention of APT. 
Aptitude, on the other hand, has very few mentions.

When I tried to see some technical comparisons, I *almost always* came across the argument that Aptitude is better than APT. Its dependency resolver is more robust than APT and it represents information in beautiful way. APT lacks some of these features.

Even if it has these plus points, Aptitude is not shipped by default on any Debian/Ubuntu based distros, and is not mentioned anywhere either. 
Also, whatever technical comparisons and mentions of Aptitude I found on the Internet are very old. (Almost 6 to 10 years old!) 
It seems that very very few people advocate Aptitude nowadays.

So my question is, why are more and more people are endorsing and promoting APT and not Aptitude? What are some technical constraints of Aptitude? In the end, distribution vendors may have some genuine reasons for this thing.

Does anyone know?

Comment: There is also a GUI tool called Synaptic, which I prefer (of course this is a solution only for desktop machines, where you have GUI, not for a server which you access via ssh and have text only interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it’s worth:

- [`apt` is installed on 99.99% of hosts](https://qa.debian.org/popcon.php?package=apt) reporting to Debian’s Popularity Contest, and used on 93% of them;
- [`aptitude` is installed on 36.31% of hosts](https://qa.debian.org/popcon.php?package=aptitude) reporting to Debian’s Popularity Contest, and used on 7.27% of them.

The fact that `apt` is installed everywhere means that any alternative needs a particularly strong story to make any headway. That doesn’t mean that `aptitude` is ignored; for example, [the Debian 11 release notes mention it extensively](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html).

There was a time when `aptitude`’s resolver was better than `apt`’s, so much so that release notes used to recommend using `aptitude` for release upgrades. That [changed in 2015](https://bugs.debian.org/780076), when it was discovered that `aptitude` couldn’t handle some upgrades from Debian 7 to Debian 8 correctly. This reflects the fact that `apt` has had significant developer investment in recent years, whereas `aptitude` is languishing.

As far as general perception goes, *e.g.* `aptitude` representation on this site v. `apt`, since `apt` is installed on all `apt`-based systems by default, anything that can be done with it is simpler to explain using it, since readers can immediately run any `apt` command. Anything done using `aptitude` needs to explain that `aptitude` first needs to be installed (see also `apt-file`).

Comment: Thanks Stephen for a detailed explanation..! I did not know about Debian's Polularity Contest. You pointed me to right direction. So we can say that, Aptitude was created as an experiment and it just struggled in experimental phase, while APT, having significant development efforts, became more preferable than Aptitude. It also came installed by default and used by lot of people. Therefore, Aptitude's popularity is less.

Comment: Also, for documentation, answering questions, etc, it is **much** easier to write (**and** understand) "run `sudo apt-get install xxx`" than it is to write "select menu foo with the keyboard or mouse, then select menu item bar, then do this, then do that".   Even people who normally use aptitude or synaptic or whatever will often use `apt` or `apt-get` in examples when telling others how to do something.

Comment: @cas I was thinking of command-line use, `aptitude install`, `aptitude search` etc. But `aptitude`’s strength is indeed its UI, and that is annoying to describe as you say.